# set readbuffer to an FBO color attachment fails with invalid enum error

Tags: linux, opengl, ati

According to the [OpenGL documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glReadBuffer.xml) I should be able to set the source for pixel reading to any of `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTi`. However, when I try this, `glGetError` gives me a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error. A subsequent `glReadPixels` simply reads the back buffer.

The version reported by `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` is `4.2.11627 Core Profile Forward-Compatible Context`. I am running on linux and have the fglrx ati drivers installed (version 8.96.7-120312a-135598C-ATI).

I checked that my FBO is bound and complete. I also verified the `glGetError` was not set by a previous call.

It fails already on this (I would expect an error here, but rather `INVALID_OPERATION` than `INVALID_ENUM`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Window.h" // My own class based on sfml, but I am sure context creation works fine
#include <glload/gll.hpp>
#include <glload/gl_core.hpp>

int main()
{
    const unsigned int screenW = 1280, screenH = 720;
    Window w(screenW, screenH, 32, false);
    if (glload::LoadFunctions() == glload::LS_LOAD_FAILED)
    {
        std::cerr << "glload failed to load" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    gl::ReadBuffer(gl::GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    if( gl::GetError() == gl::GL_INVALID_ENUM)
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid enum error" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there another reason this call could trigger `INVALID_ENUM` or is it more likely that the OpenGL implementation I am using is bugged?

Comment: Technically it is a "driver bug", but that's only because it should give you `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, not ENUM. It's an error either way; the implementation is just giving you the wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when I try this, glGetError gives me a GL_INVALID_ENUM error. A subsequent glReadPixels simply reads the back buffer.

If you're reading from the back buffer, then that means the [default framebuffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Default_Framebuffer) *is still bound*. And [`glReadBuffer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glReadBuffer) sets the reading buffer for the *current* framebuffer.

The default framebuffer doesn't have `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT`s. Therefore, setting one of these images to be the read buffer is an error. You have to bind the FBO *first*, then set the read buffer. Note that `glReadBuffer` sets the binding for the framebuffer bound to `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`, not `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`. So make sure it's bound to the right place.

Comment: You are correct. I did bind the FBO, but to `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` for rendering only, I forgot an additional bind to `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` afterwards.

Comment: @KillianDS: BTW, you may want to use the [OpenGL Wiki's version of the OpenGL API documentation](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Category:Core_API_Reference) instead of the man pages. I just changed the glReadBuffer description page to emphasize the fact that it changes the GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, for example. Good luck getting the person who maintains the man pages to do something like that.